# How to create a table like this? (Table with even length from left and right on a page in latex)

Tags: tables, margins

[image]

Hello, Please help me I have to create a table like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this tool https://www.latex-tables.com/ as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry but its not working the way I need a table.

Comment: Why? Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, I need source code as well but it is not generating something like that (the picture I have posted above). Rather a very long line which is going out of page. no columns or rows.

Comment: With that tool you can generate the same table. Have you push to the above of the page "New"? If you don't click anything and wait for the tool to respond to you, you won't get any response.

Comment: You can take this as a point to start from: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
text & text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}`